# Advice for downloading Attachments from open emails in a shared mailbox

Tags: c#, outlook

I want to create a program which will download all attachments from any open email in a shared mailbox from Outlook 2013.

I am just looking for some guidance in how to approach this as i'm not familiar with using Outlook with C#

Comment: Are you using outlook interop or what? I think the question is to broad currently. You should take smaller steps, like - hook into an existing outlook instance - define what "open email" means - get open emails - check for attachments, ... and only ask a specific question if you encounter a problem. SO is not meant to replace tutorials and other programming sources.

Comment: @grek40 OK, I will look in to that. Thanks for your advice.